# Removing the outliers improved my models, is what I did good or bad?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

I used cross validation on my data (11000 rows) with maximum salary of 10000 and after some cleaning I got to rmse=70. Then I tried to remove the outliers 10 times just to try things now I have 9000 rows with maximum salary of 260, I got rmse=23. Is what I did bad even though I got a better rmse? Is the jump from 10000 maximum to 260 a bad thing? Is the jump from 11000 rows to 9000 a bad thing?

[image: The Above one is before removing the outliers and the one under is after removing them]

Comment: That depends on the statistics of your data. Other than max, you should also share min, std and possibly 25%, 50%, 75% quantiles.

Comment: @serali I edited the question and added them (The above one is before removing the outliers and the under one is after removing them)

Comment: For which dataset have you calculated the rmse? Train or test/validation?

Comment: @spectre can you ask your question in other words? I used the cross validation with cv = 10

Comment: You've accepted a problematic answer. This is one of the reasons why it is suggested not to accept an answer for a few days.

Comment: Are you performing the validation on a set where you also remove outliers ? what are those outliers exactly ? are the extreme values due to error in 'measurement' ? are they real values in some different 'class' ?

Comment: @lcrmorin the outliers seem really non-sensical like someone getting paid 100 dollars with 16 years of experience

Comment: Probably a problem of unit no ? They would propably mean 100K. With a factor of 1000 you can just multiply anything below 1000 by 1000. It get more complex if you consider monthly v.s. yearly salary confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Removing outliers is only appropriate when you have reason to believe the data is *wrong*. Do you have such a reason? Otherwise, you are, as @Dave suggested, tricking yourself into thinking you have good predictive power.

If your data is not "nicely" distributed, and you're having trouble fitting a model to predict it, the first thing I would try is transform the `salary` field to a more usable range. For example, you can try predicting `log(salary)` or `sqrt(salary)`, then transforming it back if necessary.

Answer (score -1):

Your data is distributed very strangely, to say the least. A mean value of 178, stdev 225 and %75 is 176 is probably as far from a normal distribution as possible. But it is probably a good idea to get rid of anything out of 3 standard deviation from your mean value, that is 178 + 3*225 ~ 853.

There are different ways to deal with [skewed data](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-transform-data-to-fit-the-normal-distribution/), but for your case it is probably best to get rid of some outliers. But as @Dave points below, this lowers the predictive power for extreme values, so it is more of a judgement call.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear answer, I'll try the things you mentioned.

Comment: @FjkgB revised the normalization link to a better one, previous one was not really appropriate for this skewed data.

Comment: -1 1) We don't consider the normality of the marginal variable, and when we consider the normality of the error term (estimated by the residuals), we tend to do so for reasons of inference rather than prediction. 2) Outlier removal is fraught with problems. In this case, I would say that if you remove the outliers and find yourself making better predictions, you're only tricking yourself into thinking that you have good predictive power, but you do not have a way to handle the extreme measurements.

Comment: @Dave you should probably post this as a separate answer, OP asking whether he did good or bad.